# Not able to pass command line arguments ARGV to Ruby

Tags: ruby, testunit

```
require "selenium-webdriver"
gem "test-unit"
require "test/unit"

class GiftcardCheckout < Test::Unit::TestCase

def test_giftcard_checkout
   puts ARGV.length
end
```

I am invoking above ruby program running on Windows 7 using `ruby giftcard_checkout.rb local` from command line. The problem here is that ARGV.length is always 0 - basically the arguments are not being passed to ruby interpreter. Did go through many similar post,set the associations & file type - but did not work.

```
assoc .rb returns .rb=rbFile

ftype rbFile returns "C:\Ruby193\bin\ruby.exe" "%1" %*
```

Could this be something to do with Test Unit?

Comment: That isn’t a complete program, you will get a syntax error if you try and run it. Can you post the rest of the script?

Comment: @matt - It is a huge method so did not want to pollute this thread. I think I found the issue - looks like Test Unit acts on the ARGV value - using $arguments = ARGV.dup before class definition did the trick

Comment: Do you mean, the data in ARGV is cleared out before the test cases begin, so you make sure you copy them before the tests come in?

Comment: Yes, that is what is looks like. If I print ARGS.length (in the test method) - it returns 0.